# Body Background Image Problems

Tags: jquery, css, image, background, resize

I have a website that I have had multiple problems with the background image. The first problem was that if the screen or window was smaller than the content and the user then scrolled horizontally to see the cut-off content, the background image was cut off to the size of the window.
http://www.headstormstudios.com/sandbox/HEADSTORM/

If I could figure out the first problem a lot of other problems might solve themselves. The problem now is presented in Chrome. I used jQuery to make the background image resize to the screen size. But a large white area shows up now (sometimes have to refresh the screen for it to appear) between the image and the black footer.
http://www,headstormstudios.com

Any help with either problem would be much appreciated!!

Comment: That `<html>` element has *way* too many classes!

Comment: @Blender that's Modernizr and a font loader doing that

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` on the `body` could solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's your background-color: rgb(0,0,0) attribue on the HTML tag. I removed that and the rest of the bg image shows up

Comment: I think I fixed the problem on the version with the jQuery. I just added height:100% to the background image.